# Proving that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{3(n!)^2}{(2n+2)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, zeta-functions

Proving that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{3(n!)^2}{(2n+2)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$

I know the proving of second series which is very famous series to give us $\zeta(2)$, but I dont know how to prove the first series which is faster than second series, any help

Comment: Do you mean $3(n!)^2$ in the top of the fraction?  Otherwise the sum is infinite.

Comment: @ASCIIAdvocate yes I mean $3(n!)^2$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the series expansion of $\arcsin^2(x)$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448822/taylor-expansion-for-arcsin2x/1448880#1448880)) given by

$$\arcsin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2{2n\choose n}}$$

we see that your sum is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3(n!)^2}{(2n+2)!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3}{n^2{2n\choose n}} = 6\arcsin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: @Clayton We have $\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+2)!} = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2{2(n+1)\choose n+1}}$ then I change the summation variable $n+1\to n$.

Comment: I see; thanks.${}$