# Two formulae for $\pi$, probably known?

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, pi, hypergeometric-function

I stumbled upon (in the literature) two identities for $\pi$, but they were not referenced as they are probably well-known.  Hoping someone could point out who found them first.

Basically, the relations are:
$$\sum_{p=0}^{\lceil M/2\rceil-1}\frac{2 (M!)^2}{(2p+1)^2(M-2p-1)!(M+2p+1)!}=\sum_{m=1}^M\frac{2^{2m-1}((m-1)!)^2}{(2m)!}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Comment: Hint: the sums are rational numbers while $\pi^2/4$ is not.

Comment: @DilipSarwate But in the second one, taking $ M\rightarrow\infty$ does give $ \pi^2/4 $, according to Mathematica.  Probably this is what was intended?

Comment: Ok now I'm not sure if they are indeed converging to $\pi^2/4$, but I like where this is going... just looking for more information, so pointing out if I'm wrong is of course welcome

Comment: @StevenCharlton indeed, I find that it approaches $\pi^2/4$ in Mathematica, but I'm not sure how it computes this series.  Matlab can only compute it to $M=80$ or so..

Comment: The second sum can be written $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2m-1}}{m^2{2m\choose m}} = \arcsin^2(1) = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455698/proving-that-sum-n-0-infty-frac3n22n2-sum-n-1-infty-f/1455717#1455717) and refs within for how to derive it.