# Solve for $x, \ \frac{\pi}{5\sqrt{x + 2}} = \frac 12\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(i!)^2}{x^{2i + 1}(2i + 1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, pi

My friend gave me a question that he found on the internet, and he asked me if I knew where to begin, and I simply said, *Sorry pal, I have no idea where to begin*. That is why I would like to share this question with the MSE.

> > Solve for $x$, $$\frac{\pi}{5\sqrt{x + 2}} = \frac 12\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(i!)^2}{x^{2i + 1}(2i + 1)!}$$

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Try not to skip too many steps in the working out, and feel free to provide a hint in the end so I can have a little bit of a challenge :)

Comment: @ProfessorVector I showed my friend and told him to join many times, and he said it looks too advance, and it would be embarrassing for him to ask simple questions. I don't care to be honest whether or not my questions are embarrassing, but if he doesn't want to, I can't blame him. We are just curious teenagers who have a passion for maths (and science, particularly physics).

Comment: This is not about simple, it's about "no context, no motivation". Why would people want to waste their time with it? You may be curious and have too much time, but most won't jump at any lump of sophisticated-looking formulas. Is it (or could it be) useful for *anything*?

Comment: @ProfessorVector we don't view it as a waste of time. I told him about cool things and discoveries in maths, like the twin prime conjecture, and that is has been proven that there exist infinitely many *sexy primes*, which are prime pairs separated by a gap of $6$ numbers. He then wanted to do his own research and came across the question. I don't know where. He simply messaged me, and we were talking because it is the school holidays right now (we're in Australia). It may not be fully useful to us, but we find it interesting. Our liking for maths derived from theoretical physics.

Comment: "it would be embarrassing for him to ask simple questions" Huh?

Comment: You still didn't understand: you're speaking of *your* time. Start thinking about the time of people you expect (for some reason, but without giving them a reason) to answer.

Comment: @Did he looked at the homepage and saw *calculate this integral* and *about homogenous functions* and things like that. He at first thought it was a site for advanced mathematicians. I don't even know what those things are. I just read it and find it interesting even if I don't understand much of it. I am eager to learn, is all. This is why I have told him many times to join. But, so many *simple* questions have downvotes, so he said no. Besides, there is some personal information related to the topic which I would not want to discuss.

Comment: "Besides, there is some personal information related to the topic which I would not want to discuss" Wooohooo... Mysteries all around... // For the record, *bad* simple questions may receive downvotes (not enough of them, if you ask me) but *good* simple questions usually do not, so, you are just propagating a convenient myth here.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I don't quite see what you mean. Is this question too time-consuming to answer? And besides, why the downvotes? Are there downvotes because you think this is a *gag* and you don't like how this question came about??

Comment: Let me say first that I don't object to your question and would not down vote it.  However, I take issue with your remark about simple questions.

Simple questions get down votes not because they're simple, but because of the way they're asked.  Lot's of times the simple questions just appear to be attempts to get someone else to do their homework.  People who answer on this site are interested in helping others learn, or tackle problems that they're having problems with, but they don't come here to do others work for them.

Comment: @saulspatz Well this is not homework. My friend's mum doesn't want him to log on to sites without her permission because of cyber-safety. He doesn't even own a phone yet. We are in Year $10$. How much do I need to explain myself? You, and everyone else's interest, should revolve around the question, not the motive. If it *was* homework, I would have been honest and said so. But I have read that homework questions aren't very well accepted, and for good reason too. I have no reason to lie here. If you don't believe the *gag*, I will edit the post and lie.

Comment: I accidentally hit enter before I meant to.  Please read my complete comment above.  I'm on your side.

Comment: @saulspatz I appreciate that. I don't aim to have a full discussion here, nonetheless, and I definitely won't appreciate things like other users downvoting my post because they are unimpressed with the motive.

Comment: @saulspatz Also, at the end of the day, the *simple question* remark was posed by my friend, not me. Just to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: I will only show you how to compute the infinite sum.

Let $t = \dfrac{1}{x}$ and $f(t) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}t^{2n+1}$ and observe that $f'(t) =1+ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}}$ as well as $$\int_{0}^t\tfrac{f'(u)-1}{u}du = \sum\limits_{n= 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^{2n}}{2n\binom{2n}{n}} = \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{4-t^2}}\arcsin\frac{t}{2}$$
when the latter is known as [Lehmer's identity](http://emis.ams.org/journals/JIS/VOL19/Chen/chen21.pdf) and is valid when $|t|<2.$

Comment: You and @RobertZ each helped me to work out that $x=\phi$ so thank you very much. However, I will mark your answer with a $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ because it is clearer, so congratulations $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice, that for $|z|<1$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{(2z)^{2i}}{\binom{2i}{i}}
=\frac1{1-z^2}\left[z^2+\frac{z\arcsin(z)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\right]$$
(for a proof see [Does the series $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{i-1}(i-1)!}{\prod_{j=1}^{i}(2j+1)}$ converge and if so, to what?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942940/does-the-series-sum-i-1-infty-frac2i-1i-1-prod-j-1i2j1?noredirect=1&lq=1))
and by integration we get
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(2z)^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)\binom{2i}{i}}=
\frac{2\arcsin(z)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}.$$
Then by letting $2z=1/x$, your equation is
$$\frac{\pi}{5\sqrt{x + 2}} = \frac 12\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(1/x)^{2i + 1}}{(2i + 1)\binom{2i}{i}}=\frac{\arcsin(1/(2x))}{\sqrt{1-1/(2x)^2}}.$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. The unique solution should be the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) $x=\varphi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ (recall that $\sin(\pi/10)=1/(2\varphi)$).

Comment: I liked your answer very much, but it did not explain how I was able to notice the first equation. The proof is great, but the other answer is simpler and does not require a supporting theorem. I apologise for not giving you a $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ but both the answers were very nice. Yours helped me most, but it was from the other answer that I was able to draw both conclusions together since it was clearer. Thank you very much though :)

Comment: @user477343 The unique solution should be the golden ratio $x=\varphi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$

Comment: I knew that :) but thx anyway

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) integral:
$$
\int_0^1t^k(1-t)^k\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{k!^2}{(2k+1)!}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!^2}{(2k+1)!}x^{-2k-1}
&=\frac1{2x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{t^k(1-t)^k}{x^{2k}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac1{2x}\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{x^2-t(1-t)}\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
&=\frac x2\int_0^1\frac1{\left(t-\frac12\right)^2+x^2-\frac14}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac x{2\sqrt{x^2-\frac14}}\int_{-\frac1{2\sqrt{x^2-\frac14}}}^{\frac1{2\sqrt{x^2-\frac14}}}\frac1{t^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}\right)\\[9pt]
&=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac1{|2x|}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I would have voted if I hadn’t reached my limit, hah. I can vote in $15$ hours :)

Comment: @robjohn It should be $\frac{2|x|}{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac1{2x}\right)$. The LHS is an odd function. Am I right?

Comment: @RobertZ: actually, it should be the argument to arcsin that is always positive, but yes, it should be odd.