# Does this sequence converge or not

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether or not the following sequence converges
$$(2n)!\over{(n!)^2}$$
Please help me with which method i need to use to prove this

Comment: It obviously does, 2n! grows faster than n!^2

Comment: @mtheorylord Which means that it diverges. But you're technically right: any sequence converges or not:)

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606836/why-does-this-series-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-converge/1606870

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually the binomial coefficient of $2n$ and $n$, which clearly does not approach any defined value. See this post:

[prove that $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ is even if $n$ is a positive integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78533/prove-that-frac2nn2-is-even-if-n-is-a-positive-integer)