# On the Taylor coefficients of $\arcsin^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, power-series

The Maclaurin series of $\arcsin^2$ and $\arcsin^4$ are fairly well-known,
$$ \arcsin^2(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{2n^2\binom{2n}{n}},\qquad \arcsin^4(x)=3\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_{n-1}^{(2)}(2x)^{2n}}{2n^2\binom{2n}{n}} $$
but in order to deal with some logarithmic integrals I need the Maclaurin series of $\arcsin^3(x)$.

[Mr. Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html) states this is a result of Ramanujan, but I have not been able to find it in his notebooks, so I would like some help. Any derivation from scratch is clearly just as welcome.

Comment: Supposedly it's proven in J. Edwards, Differential Calculus, MacMillan, London, UK, 2nd edition, 1982 but I can't find that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See Ramanujan's Notebooks. Part 1 at page 263[image]
For  a more general result see also the paper ["Integer Powers of Arcsin"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7028/3a3c2a4899ab28edef2d66209a5cb93c208c.pdf) by J. M. Borwein and M. Chamberland.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I included a more general reference.

Comment: By the way

$$1+\frac1{3^2}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac1{(2k-1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}=H_{2k}^{(2)}-\frac14H_k^{(2)}$$

Answer (score 2):

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $|x|<1$, the function $\bigl(\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\bigr)^{k}$, whose value at $x=0$ is defined to be $1$, has Maclaurin's series expansion
\begin{equation}\label{arcsin-series-expansion-unify}
\biggl(\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\biggr)^{k}
=1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^m\frac{Q(k,2m)}{\binom{k+2m}{k}}\frac{(2x)^{2m}}{(2m)!},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}\label{Q(m-k)-sum-dfn}
Q(k,m)=\sum_{\ell=0}^{m} \binom{k+\ell-1}{k-1} s(k+m-1,k+\ell-1)\biggl(\frac{k+m-2}{2}\biggr)^{\ell}
\end{equation}
for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\ge2$. In particular, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\arcsin x}{x}&=1!\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(2n-1)!!]^2\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!},\\
\biggl(\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\biggr)^2&=2!\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [(2n)!!]^2 \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+2)!},\\
\biggl(\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\biggr)^3 &=3!\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(2n+1)!!]^2 \Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}\Biggr]\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+3)!},\\
\biggl(\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\biggr)^4&=4!\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(2n+2)!!]^2\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k+2)^2}\Biggr] \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+4)!},\\
\biggl(\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\biggr)^5&=\frac{5!}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(2n+3)!!]^2 \Biggl[\Biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}\Biggr)^2 -\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^4}\Biggr] \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+5)!}.
\end{align}
These results have been reviewed and surveyed in the papers [2, 3] below, recovered in the paper [1] below, and generalized in the paper [4] below.

References

1. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.
2. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **16** (2022), no. 2, 427--466; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
3. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Series expansions of powers of arcsine, closed forms for special values of Bell polynomials, and series representations of generalized logsine functions*, AIMS Mathematics **6** (2021), no. 7, 7494--7517; available online at https://doi.org/10.3934/math.2021438.
4. F. Qi, *Explicit formulas for partial Bell polynomials, Maclaurin's series expansions of real powers of inverse (hyperbolic) cosine and sine, and series representations of powers of Pi*, Research Square (2021), available online at https://doi.org/10.21203/rs.3.rs-959177/v3.

Comment: Related links: 

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4270180,
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4379986,
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4379999,
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4380027,
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657809.