# Simplifying $\sin(a\arcsin(x))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, special-functions

I am trying to simplify:
$$f_a(x)=\sin(a\arcsin(x))$$
We can write:
$$f_a(x)=\frac{1}{2} i \left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+i x\right)^{-a}-\frac{1}{2} i \left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+i x\right)^a$$
I tried using the binomial expansion:
$$f_a(x)=\frac{i}{2} (i x)^{-a} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{i x}\right)^n \binom{-a}{n}-\frac{i}{2} (i x)^a \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{i x}\right)^n \binom{a}{n}$$
but it does not seem to lead anywhere… Does this expression relate somehow to some special functions?

EDIT:

Supported by Mathematica I found the following pattern:
$$f_a(x)\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}a\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (a^2-(2j+1)^2) $$

Comment: "it does not seem to lead anywhere": where exactly would "somewhere" be? For instance do we agree that if we solved your question, then we could write $\sin(ax)=f_a(\sin x)$ for $\lvert x\rvert\le \frac\pi2$, and that $f_n(x)=U_{n-1}(\sqrt{1-x^2}) x$ for $n\in \Bbb Z$, where $U_n$ is the n-th Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind?

Comment: Both of these forms are useful, thank you.

Comment: I guess then $g_a(x)=\cos(a \arcsin(x))$ gives $g_a(\sin(x))=\cos(a x)$ and therefore $g_n(x)=T_n(\sqrt{1-x^2})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem.** For $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|x|<1$, we have
\begin{equation}\label{sin-arcsin-ser}\tag{T}
\sin(\alpha\arcsin x)=\alpha\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Biggl(\prod_{\ell=1}^{k}\bigl[(2\ell-1)^2-\alpha^2\bigr]\Biggr) \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.
\end{equation}

**Proof.**
Let $f_\alpha(x)=\sin(\alpha\arcsin x)$. Then
\begin{gather*}
f_\alpha'(x)=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\cos(\alpha\arcsin x)=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\sqrt{1-f_\alpha^2(x)}\,\\
\bigl(1-x^2\bigr)\bigl[f_\alpha'(x)\bigr]^2-\alpha^2\bigl[1-f_\alpha^2(x)\bigr]=0,\\
\bigl(1-x^2\bigr)f_\alpha''(x)-xf_\alpha'(x)+\alpha^2f_\alpha(x)=0,\\
\bigl(1-x^2\bigr)f_\alpha^{(3)}(x)-3xf_\alpha''(x)+\bigl(\alpha^2-1\bigr)f_\alpha'(x)=0,\\
\bigl(1-x^2\bigr)f_\alpha^{(4)}(x)-5xf_\alpha^{(3)}(x)+\bigl(\alpha^2-4\bigr)f_\alpha''(x)=0,
\end{gather*}
and, inductively,
\begin{equation}\label{n-deriv-gen+alpha-sin}\tag{P}
\bigl(1-x^2\bigr)f_\alpha^{(k+2)}(x)-(2k+1)xf_\alpha^{(k+1)}(x)+\bigl(\alpha^2-k^2\bigr)f_\alpha^{(k)}(x)=0, \quad k\ge0.
\end{equation}
Letting $x\to0$ in \eqref{n-deriv-gen+alpha-sin} results in
\begin{equation}\label{n-deriv-x=0+alpha-sin}\tag{Q}
f_\alpha^{(k+2)}(0)+\bigl(\alpha^2-k^2\bigr)f_\alpha^{(k)}(0)=0, \quad k\ge0.
\end{equation}
Recusing the relation \eqref{n-deriv-x=0+alpha-sin} and considering $f_\alpha(0)=0$ and $f_\alpha'(0)=\alpha$ arrive at
\begin{equation*}
f^{(2k)}(0)=0
\quad\text{and}\quad
f^{(2k+1)}(0)=\alpha \prod_{\ell=1}^{k}\bigl[(2\ell-1)^2-\alpha^2\bigr]
\end{equation*}
for $k\ge0$. Consequently, the series expansion \eqref{sin-arcsin-ser} is valid.

**Remark.** For details of the above result and its proof, please refer to the equation (3.22) in Lemma 3.3 in the paper [1] below. For more information on related results, please refer to the papers [2,3,4,5] below.

**References**

1. F. Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of functions containing squares of inverse (hyperbolic) cosine functions, explicit formulas for special partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for powers of circular constant*, arXiv (2021), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.02749v2.
2. B.-N. Guo, D. Lim, and F. Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Appl. Anal. Discrete Math. **16** (2022), in press; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
3. B.-N. Guo, D. Lim, and F. Qi, *Series expansions of powers of arcsine, closed forms for special values of Bell polynomials, and series representations of generalized logsine functions*, AIMS Math. **6** (2021), no. 7, 7494--7517; available online at https://doi.org/10.3934/math.2021438.
4. F. Qi, *Explicit formulas for partial Bell polynomials, Maclaurin's series expansions of real powers of inverse (hyperbolic) cosine and sine, and series representations of powers of Pi*, Research Square (2021), available online at https://doi.org/10.21203/rs.3.rs-959177/v3.
5. F. Qi and M. D. Ward, *Closed-form formulas and properties of coefficients in Maclaurin's series expansion of Wilf's function*, arXiv (2021), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v1.

Comment: Thank you very much for this input

Answer (score 2):

This is based on my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4157803. Let
$$
g(x) = e^{ia\arcsin x}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {g_n x^n } .
$$
Then $g(x)$ satisfies the non-linear ODE $(1 - x^2 )(g'(x))^2  = -a^2g^2 (x)$. Differentiating this equation and dividing through by $2g'(x)$ yields
$$
(1 - x^2 )g''(x) - xg'(x) + a^2 g(x) = 0.
$$
Substituting the power series into this equation gives $g_0  = 1$, $g_1  = ia$ (you can see from the definition that $g(0) = 1$, $g'(0) = ia$) and
$$
g_{n + 2}  = \frac{{n^2-a^2}}{{(n + 1)(n + 2)}}g_n 
$$
for $n\geq 0$. The power series expansion then follows since
$$
f_a(x) = \Im g(x).
$$
Your function can also be written in terms of the Gauss hypergeometric function:
$$
f_a (x) = ax \cdot {}_2F_1\! \left( {1 - a,1+a;\tfrac{3}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}(1 - \sqrt {1 - x^2 } )} \right).
$$