# Prove that $e^\frac{\pi}{2}=1+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{5}{24}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{85}{720}+\frac{520}{5040}+\frac{3145}{40320}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

I misused the Taylor series to represent $e^x$ as a combination of sin(x) functions

Assume:
$e^x=a_0+a_1\sin(x)+a_2\sin^2(x)+a_3\sin^3(x)+\cdots$

The sequence coefficients are:$a_0=1;a_1=1;a_2=\frac{1}{2};a_3=\frac{2}{6};a_4=\frac{5}{24};a_5=\frac{20}{120};a_6=\frac{85}{720};a_7=\frac{520}{5040};a_8=\frac{3145}{40320}\cdots$

Therefore we have,

$e^\tfrac{\pi}{2}=1+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{6}+\frac{5}{24}+\frac{20}{120}+\frac{85}{720}+\frac{520}{5040}+\frac{3145}{40320}+\cdots$

Additionally we have, $e^\tfrac{\pi}{6}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\times2^2}+\frac{2}{6\times2^3}+\frac{5}{24\times2^4}+\frac{20}{120\times2^5}+\frac{85}{720\times2^6}+\frac{518}{5040\times2^7}+\frac{3145}{40320\times2^8}+\cdots$

The summation values do seem to be nearly equal to the LHS after a few terms. However I am skeptical and would like to know if this misrepresentation of the Taylor series is valid.

I would appreciate any other proofs for the derived value of $e^\tfrac{\pi}{2}$ or $e^\tfrac{\pi}{6} $ to corroborate the summation.

Comment: May I ask you how did you derive $a_i$ from your assumption?

Comment: The numerators match [OEIS A006228](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C5%2C20%2C85%2C&language=english&go=Search), except for $a_7$ which has numerator $518$. Are you sure it is not $520$?

Comment: I think you may be unfairly judged for this question, due to it not being super specific and rigorous in its reasoning, but I see where you are coming from and actually like this question and exploration. But yeah I am with SBF on this one lol, getting that sequence I would assume is rather non-trivial lol

Comment: @PHHerman the summation works analogous to normal Taylor series. Since the terms after the first have sinx in common. You can try it with the derivative calculator, the terms cancel out and you only have to deal with one term for the most part when x=0. The previous terms do come into the picture after a few iterations, which I can't recognise the pattern of though :)

Comment: @TymaGaidash great find!! I must have made a mistake somewhere

Comment: If you let $y=\sin x$ then you are looking at the Taylor series of $e^{\sin^{-1} y}$ when $y=1$ and later when $y=\frac12$.  This is not a misrepresentation.  The $\,^7$ coefficient is $\frac{13}{126}=\frac{520}{7!}$ not $\frac{518}{7!}$

Comment: @Lithium It is indeed $520$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+exp%28asin%28x%29%29) for example (click “more terms”).

Comment: It's a bit outside the scope of this question but there is a fantastic solution to asking the question of IF a continuous function can be represented by a particular infinite solution. And that involves the generalised Stone-Weierstrass theorem. PREtty neat theorem for these types of problems. Doesn't give you coefficients but helps in checking if it is even possible to do so

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4157803

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $F(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 + \dots$, then your equation is
$$
e^x = F(\sin x) .
$$
So, solving,
$$
F(z) = \exp(\arcsin z) .
$$
near $z=0$.
Maple computes this Taylor series
$$
\exp(\arcsin z) = 
1+z+{\frac{1}{2}}{z}^{2}+{\frac{1}{3}}{z}^{3}+{\frac{5}{24}}{z}^{4}+{
\frac{1}{6}}{z}^{5}+{\frac{17}{144}}{z}^{6}+{\frac{13}{126}}{z}^{7}+{
\frac{629}{8064}}{z}^{8}+\dots 
$$
and this agrees with your values.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from @GEdgar's answer, you could as many terms as you wish since
$$F(z) = \exp(\arcsin( z))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,z^n$$ with
$$a_n=\frac{\left(n^2-4 n+5\right) }{(n-1) n}\,a_{n-2}\qquad \text{with}\qquad a_0=a_1=1$$

Computing the partial sums with $z=1$ $$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$ you will need a lot of terms since $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ happens to be larger than $1$; so, for $z=1$, it will probably not converge. Converted to decimals, the results are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 10 & 3.63555 \\
 20 & 3.96602 \\
 30 & 4.11724 \\
 40 & 4.20849 \\
 50 & 4.27117 \\
 60 & 4.31763 \\
 70 & 4.35384 \\
 80 & 4.38308 \\
 90 & 4.40734 \\
 100 & 4.42789 \\
 200 & 4.53951 \\
 300 & 4.58912 \\
 400 & 4.61872 \\
 500 & 4.63894 \\
 600 & 4.65387 \\
 700 & 4.66547 \\
 800 & 4.67483 \\
 900 & 4.68258 \\
 1000 & 4.68914 \\
 2000 & 4.72467 \\
 3000 & 4.74041 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

But, using $z=\frac 9 {10}$, it does converge like a charm

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 10 & 2.97617 \\
 20 & 3.04968 \\
 30 & 3.06103 \\
 40 & 3.06339 \\
 50 & 3.06395 \\
 60 & 3.06409 \\
 70 & 3.06413 \\
 80 & 3.06414 \\
 90 & 3.06415 \\
 100 & 3.06415 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Just a remark :

Use $x>1$:

$$e^{\arctan\left(x\right)}<\int_{x}^{x+1}e^{\arctan\left(y\right)}dy<e^{\arctan\left(x+1\right)}$$

Then use Riemann sum.

Another attempt should be to use :

$$\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(2k+2\right)^{2}}{\left(2k+1\right)\left(2k+3\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Edit :

I have now a strategy let me share it :

1. show for $x,y\in[1,\infty)$ :

$$|xe^{\arctan(x)}-ye^{\arctan(y)}|\leq \exp(\pi/2)|x-y|$$

2)Show there exists a small $\varepsilon>0$ such that :

$$\int_{x}^{x+1}ye^{\arctan(y)}dy +\frac{1}{2}\exp(\pi/2)-\varepsilon\leq (x+1)e^{\arctan(x+1)}$$

3)Find a similar upper bound as in 2)

4)Make the difference in 2) and 3) and use Riemann's sum

5)Final step using @TymaGaidash finding  ( OEIS A006228) show that if $AB=k$ and $AC=k$ it implies $B=C$

Comment: Repeating the algorithm (ignoring some term) we have dividing by $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ at each iteration and making the difference to get a rational the series begin with : $$S=((1)/(2))+((4)/(3))+((5)/(4))+((15)/(8))+((35)/(24))+((35)/(16))+((105)/(24))+((105)/(16))+((315)/(32))+((945)/(64))+13.94+6.96+3.561+1.718+0.756+0.366+0.1738+((0.1738)/(2))+((0.1738)/(4))+((0.1738)/(8))+((0.1738)/(16))+((0.1738)/(32))+((0.1738)/(64))+((0.1738)/(128))+\cdots$$ .then $$I=ln(S/e^{(pi/2)})$$ so $$\int_{0}^{1}x!dx\simeq S-e^{\gamma}$$