# How do i evaluate $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{((\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor-1)!)^2}{(2\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor-1)!}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, indefinite-integrals

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{((\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor-1)!)^2}{(2\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor-1)!}dx$$

**What I do so far**

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{((\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor-1)!)^2}{(2\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor-1)!}dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{((n-1)!)^2}{(2n-1)!}dx$$

$$\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{((n-1)!)^2}{(2n-1)!}dx = \frac{((n-1)!)^2}{(2n-1)!} \cdot (n+1 - n) = \frac{((n-1)!)^2}{(2n-1)!}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{((n-1)!)^2}{(2n-1)!}$$ = \begin{align*}
\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, the area under the graph of the integrand is just rectangles with width one, so it's the same as summing the heights of those rectangles. I might look at the first few terms of the sum for a nice pattern (but if the answer involves $\pi$ like that, it maybe won't be so simple). Otherwise I'd try finding a formula for the generating function.

Comment: How did you compute your last sum of the factorials?

Comment: Wolfram alpha? Amy ideas how to solve last sum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sum can be evaluated from a special case of the more general series expansion
$$\arcsin^2 x = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}}. \tag{1}$$
Taking the derivative, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
\frac{2 \arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} 
&= 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n-1}}{n \binom{2n}{n}} \\
&= 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n! \, (n-1)!}{(2n)!}(2x)^{2n-1} \\
&= 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2n} \frac{(n-1)!^2}{(2n-1)!} (2x)^{2n-1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n-1)!^2}{(2n-1)!} (2x)^{2n-1}. \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
Your sum is $(2)$ evaluated at $x = 1/2$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n-1)!^2}{(2n-1)!} = \frac{2 \arcsin \frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{3/4}} = \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}. \tag{3}$$
The identity $(1)$ is Equation $(19)$ in the [MathWorld entry for inverse sine](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html), which cites Borwein (2004) but as I do not have this text, I cannot provide a proof at this time.

Comment: Thanks alot, great +1

Comment: For completion's sake, I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1448822/695196) for the proof of $\arcsin^2(x)$'s Taylor series, and also [this](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Reihenentwicklungen#Potenzen_des_Arkussinus) resource.

Comment: @RobertLee The top answer there references [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549028/deriving-maclaurin-series-for-frac-arcsin-x-sqrt1-x2#649761) which is actually more directly related to this sum in the first place.

Comment: (I was also able to get the same formula starting from the sum and finding a differential equation for its generating function.)