# Power Summation Over the Divisor Function

Tags: number-theory, power-series, divisor-sum, upper-lower-bounds

For integers $a,b,k$, how would one evaluate (or find an upper/lower bound) to $$\sum_{n≤k}\frac{\sigma(n)^a}{n^b}$$ Where $\sigma(n)$ denotes the [divisor sigma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html)?

$\bf{Edit:}$
More specifically, how would one evaluate $$\sum_{n≤k}\frac{(\sigma(n)-n)^s}{n^{s-1}}$$ for some integer $s>2$?

Comment: I know that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sigma _a(n)}{n^b}=\zeta (b) \zeta (b-a)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is well-known that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_order_of_an_arithmetic_function):
$$ \sum_{n\leq x}\sigma(n) = \frac{\pi^2}{12} x^2 + O(x)\tag{1} $$
and the average order of $\sigma(n)^a$ can be derived from Euler's product and [tauberian theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem).
For instance

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sigma(n)^2}{n^s}&=&\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{(p+1)^2}{p^s}+\frac{(1+p+p^2)^2}{p^{2s}}+\ldots\right)\\&=&\prod_p\frac{1-\frac{1}{p^{2s-2}}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s-1}}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s-2}}\right)}\\&=&\frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(s-1)^2\zeta(s-2)}{\zeta(2s-2)}\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
leads to
$$ \sum_{n\leq x}\sigma(n)^2 = \frac{5\zeta(3)}{6} x^3+O(x^2)\tag{3} $$
and $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)^2}{n^b}$ can be estimated through summation by parts. Of course the behaviour of $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)^a}{n^b}$ strongly depends on $b>(a+1)$ (leading to a convergent series) $b=(a+1)$ (leading to a slowly divergent series) or $b<(a+1)$ (leading to a polynomial bound).

Comment: See edit... I'm trying to evaluate the sum in the edit by expanding the polynomial in the numerator and obtaining asymptotic approximations for each term as $k$ tends to infinity

Comment: @Romain: if I did not mess up, the above technique leads to $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{(\sigma(n)-n)^2}{n}=\frac{6-2\pi^2+15\zeta(3)}{12}x^2+O(x)$$ for $s=2$, but computations are not that pleasant for a generic $s>2$.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. For clarification, how did you use hardy littlewoods's tauberian theorem to get from (2) to (3)?

Comment: @Romain: I used the tauberian theorem to derive $(3)$ from $(2)$: the abscissa of convergence of the series in $(2)$ is $\sigma=3$ and by the asymptotic behaviour of $\frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(s-1)^2\zeta(s-2)}{\zeta(2s-2)}$ in a right neighbourhood of $s=3$ the statement $(3)$ follows.