# Euler's transformation to derive that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

According to the accepted answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726187/sum-of-reciprocals-of-squares-bounding/1808882#1808882), we can apply Euler's series transformation to derive that $$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}}.$$ I am wondering, how can we do that? Can you provide me an explanation?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Help is needed here!

Comment: It is enough to adapt the technique shown here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2331708/44121

Comment: See also page $4$ of my course notes - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwcGlSbzgzZVdYZkk/view (sorry, they are in Italian)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks a lot, I 'll check both links.

Comment: Please stop using `\displaystyle` in titles.

Comment: @Did OK, but why?

Comment: @SachpazisStelios: it messes things up when listing questions in the home page, better to avoid it, nothing personal.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio OK, I got it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proof by pure creative telescoping has been linked in the comments above, but there also is an interesting proof that comes from manipulations of a logarithmic integral.

If we set
$$ I = -\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\sin^2 x\right)\frac{dx}{\sin x}$$
by expanding $-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\sin^2 x\right)$ as a Taylor series in $\sin x$ we get that
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{blue}{I} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n 4^n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{2n-1}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{4n(2n-1)\binom{2n-2}{n-1}}=\color{blue}{ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
and by applying the tangent half-angle substitution we get that:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}-\log\left(1-\left(\frac{t}{1+t^2}\right)^2\right)\frac{dt}{t} $$
where the rational function $1-\left(\frac{t}{1+t^2}\right)^2$ can be expressed through products and ratios of polynomials of the form$1-t^m$. *Eureka*, since:
$$ I_m=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-t^m)}{t} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1}t^{mn-1}\,dt = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{mn^2}=-\frac{\zeta(2)}{m}$$
implies:
$$ \color{blue}{I} = \left(I_2-2 I_4+I_6\right)=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{6}\zeta(2)}$$
as wanted.

---

Since we have
$$ 2\arcsin^2(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}} $$
as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878477/a-closed-form-of-sum-k-0-infty-frac-1k1k-gamma2-left-frack2), the acceleration formula implies that $\zeta(2)=6\arcsin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.