# Do similar expressions exist for odd zeta values other than $3$?

Tags: summation, riemann-zeta

Since Hjortnaes (and later Apéry), we know that

$$
\zeta(3)=\frac{5}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{ (-1)^{k-1}} {k^{3}\binom {2k}{k}}}.
$$

I read somewhere that there might be a similar expression for $\zeta(5)$:

$$
\zeta(5)=\frac{a}{b} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{ (-1)^{k-1}} {k^{5}\binom {2k}{k}}},
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive nonzero integers. I know that no such $a$ and $b$ have been found yet, otherwise Apéry's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ could be extended to $\zeta(5)$. Are there any results suggesting that *there exist* similar sums for $\zeta(2n+1)$, $n>1$:

$$
\zeta(2n+1)=\frac{a}{b} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{ (-1)^{k-1}} {k^{2n+1}\binom {2k}{k}}}?
$$

Conversely, are there any results that *rule out* the existence of such sums for certain odd positive integers?

Finally, what are the current known bounds on $a$ and $b$, if such sums *can* exist?

Comment: The paper by Nan-Yue and Williams [1] is worth consulting; equation (4.20) onwards involving the golden ratio $\Phi$.

( [1] Nan-Yue, Zhang; Williams, Kenneth S. Values of the Riemann zeta function and integrals involving $\log(2\,{\rm sinh}(\theta/2))$ and $\log(2\sin(\theta/2))$. Pacific J. Math. 168 (1995), no. 2, 271--289. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102620561 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first terms of the continued fraction of 
$$ \frac{1}{\zeta(5)}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^5 \binom{2k}{k}} $$
are given by 
$$[0; 2, 10, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 66, 4, 135, 3, 1, \
6, 1, 29,\ldots]$$
so if the previous number is $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have $\min(a,b)>3\cdot 10^{12}$.
In other terms, it looks pretty unlikely that the series $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^5 \binom{2k}{k}}$ provides a rational multiple of $\zeta(5)$.
The classical results
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{1}{3}\zeta(2),\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{2}{5}\zeta(3),\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^4\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{17}{36}\zeta(4)$$
(stating that in some cases the hypergeometric $\phantom{}_{p+1} F_p\left(1,1,1\ldots;\tfrac{3}{2},2,2,\ldots;\pm\tfrac{1}{4}\right)$ has a nice closed form in terms of the $\zeta$ function) can be seen as consequences of [creative telescoping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331692/why-does-sum-1-infty-frac1n3-frac52-sum-1-infty-frac-1n-1n3-bi/2331708#2331708), or as consequences of symmetry relations for polylogarithms (see [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389425/a-very-odd-looking-statement-about-zeta3-and-textli-2-left-frac1-va)). About $\frac{1}{k^5}$, creative telescoping produces spurious terms and the functional relations for $\text{Li}_4$ and $\text{Li}_5$ are pretty messy, so there are substantial obstructions in generalizing the classical approaches for producing a simple irrationality proof for $\zeta(5)$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please point me to an article that describes the hypergeometric function as closed forms in terms of $\zeta$? That would be an interesting read.

Comment: @PreservedFruit: here it is a good one - https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1591

Comment: Thank you for the link!